# what's wrong with my quick sort algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

I am trying to fix my quicksort code, and I have no idea why it is not working. It gives me all kind of errors when I try to run it. I tried changing a couple things but not sure about what direction to go. Would some one please help me

```
   import java.util.Random;
        public class ModifiedQuickSort {
    // main quicksort method
            public static void quickSort(String[] array){
                int low = 0;
                int high = array.length-1;
                if(high > low)
                {
                    int pivot = partition(low, high, array);
                    partition(low, pivot - 1, array);
                    partition(pivot + 1, high, array);
                }
            }
    // Method to partion the array
            public static int partition(int low, int high,String[] array ){
                int i, j = low;
                Random rand = new Random();
                int pivot = rand.nextInt((high-low)+1) + 1;
                for( i = low + 1; i<= high; i++){
                    if(array[i].compareToIgnoreCase(array[j]) < pivot){
                        j++;
                        String temp = array[i];
                        array[i] = array[j];
                        array[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
                String temp = array[low];
                array[low] = array [j];
                array[j] = temp;
                return j;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please post the errors and sample input/output.

Comment: It is just not organizing the arrays at this point.

Comment: As quicksort is very common algorithm and there are lot of questions and answer around it but since you have posted it, you may get the answer if users see what issue you are getting, problem is visible to you but may be not to us.

Comment: This is obviously incorrect, though I don't think it's the only error: `if(array[i].compareToIgnoreCase(array[j]) < pivot){`

Comment: I can't seem to find a recursive call.

Comment: What was the change since the tests last passed? OR did you write all that code before running a test? see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B93QezwTQpI for how TTD can be used to discover quick sort.

Comment: I have looked at your code. It is not quicksort and it contains part of bubble sort.Your code contains a lot of mutation (changing the state of variables). This will make it hard to implement quick-sort. I would recommend learning to do things one step at a time, learning TDD, and learning functional design (functional programming techniques). I can't tell you what your next step is, as I don't know your background.